# Generating temporary passwords/tokens using RNG

Tags: passwords, key-generation

In my web application I generate temporary tokens/passwords for accessing files using this method:

```
ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_"
ALPHABET_LENGTH = 64

def generate_token(str_len = 22)
   res = ""
   str_len.times{res << ALPHABET[rand(ALPHABET_LENGTH)]}
   res
end
```

Is there any vulnerability in generating tokens/passwords this way?

If it matters, a generated token lives 7 days.

Answer (score 7):

Since it looks like you are using Ruby's default RNG, the Mersenne Twister, it is possible for an attacker to obtain the seed of the RNG, and therefore compromise all past, present, and future numbers generated by the algorithm using something like [mt_derand](https://github.com/GeorgeArgyros/mt_derand). It is probably a better idea to use SecureRandom instead.

Comment: While that's strictly true, it's unlikely that all randomness is obtained from a single instance of the RNG, especially on a webserver that probably runs multiple threads or processes.

Comment: 1) `it is possible for an attacker to obtain the seed of the RNG,` ---> how?

Comment: 2) what should I use instead? secure hash function?

Comment: If you'd like to use SecureRandom instead of rand, you would just replace 
`str_len.times{res << ALPHABET[rand(ALPHABET_LENGTH)]}`
with
`str_len.times{res << ALPHABET[SecureRandom.random_number(ALPHABET_LENGTH)]}`
and include `require 'securerandom'` at the top of your code

Comment: @LamerZ, that's not what I asked about

Comment: @Ramito 1) Read the link to mt_derand
2) You should use SecureRandom instead

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the quality of the `rand` function.

If it's not a secure random number generator (and in particular if it's a standard function from a known framework), then yes: an attacker could analyse a number of sequentially generated tokens and have a good chance of finding out the internal state of the RNG, allowing him to extrapolate a new token from an existing valid one.

Comment: what should I use instead? secure hash function?

Comment: A secure hash function using a cryptographically secure RNG and a good source of enthropy. e.g. https://github.com/cryptosphere/sysrandom (I haven't tested or even evalutaed it beyond the projects page but it looks like it's doing things right)

Comment: what my "rand" is implemented using that or similar function already?